# matrix lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

We know the set of one-parameter subgroup generators of a (closed) matrix lie group G (a subgroup of a general linear group) is closed under lie bracket and addition. In  fact I see that in most places a matrix lie group is defined to be topologically closed. Is there a counter example? A subgroup of the general linear group, not closed, whose set of one-parameter generators are not closed under addition or the lie bracket?

Comment: Isn't the Lie bracket defined on the algebra associated to the group? E.g. in $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ we have $[\hat{1},\hat{1}]=0$ where $\hat{1}$ is the identity: it is obviously in $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ but $0$ isn't.

Comment: @Davide F The set of 1-parameters generators of the general linear group is the set of all square matrices, not the group itself. So your counter example does not work.

Comment: I think this quesiton is based on a partial misunderstanding. The role of closedness of a matrix group is not to ensure that the set of exponential generators form a Lie subalgebra. This is indeed true for many non-closed subgroups. You need closedness of the group in order to make it into a submanifold in the space of matrices, which allows you to do analysis on your group. For example, you can then form the derivative of a homomorphism at the identity matrix, which is needed to get information out of the space of exponential generators.

Comment: @ Andreas Cap it is not based on a misunderstanding. I know what you stated already. Can you answer the question or a reference where it might have examples ?